# GUI Performance Monitor Tool

Tags: performance

I need to monitor the performance of an Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I am looking for a tool similar to PerfMon on Windows.

I need something more interactive that using `top` from a terminal ; I am looking for something both interactive and GUI-based.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You should probably enumerate the features from perfmon on windows that you like (especially as Ubuntu people are less likely to have used windows software).   BTW, `htop` is a worthwhile (still CLI) improvement `top`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the default System Monitor. Launch it from terminal with `gnome-system-monitor` or search for System Monitor/Task Manager on the search window in the sidebar. If you prefer to use terminal based system monitor, try `htop` or `nmon`

Comment: what is the location to access the default system monitor , are you talking about typing top in terminal I am interested in GUI based tool

Comment: It's GUI based. It's like Windows Task Manager. Type gnome-system-monitor on the terminal.

Comment: Can i access the default performance monitor from the global search

Comment: Yeah you can, search `Task Manager` (or System Monitor)

Comment: Can you please try to expand this into a more full fledged answer? Right now it's just one sentence that doesn't even really explain what tool you're talking about. Thanks.

Comment: @Seth is this enough??!

Comment: Yeah that's better. A screenshot would be cool too though.

Answer (score 10):

A particular flavor of `top` that we use here is `htop`. Still CLI based but much more 'graphical'.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Answer (score 0):

run `top` in terminal.

There are other flavors or top as well but they need to be downloaded.

Comment: I am interested in GUI based tool to monitor the performance , but will try top in terminal.  Thanks for the solution

Comment: i saw top today when i typed top on terminal , basically it just lists the processes and their cpu usage in a tabular form I am looking for more interactive way to view performance

Answer (score 0):

I've found KSysGuard a more powerful than System Monitor, but they both suffer from the same problem: inaccurate CPU utilization readings, and stale processes. I see processes in KSysGuard that I have quit long ago. Restarting it no longer shows them, but that confirms it's a bug.